# JSON.Net Converting XML into JSON

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I have following xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XslMapper>
  <type name="article" xsl="http://localhost:8080/Xsl-a.xslt">
    <category name="1234" xsl="http://localhost:8080/Xsl-b.xslt"></category>
    <category name="1234" xsl="http://localhost:8080/Xsl-b.xslt"></category>
  </type>
  <type name="slideshow" xsl="http://localhost:8080/Xsl-c.xslt" >
    <category name="1234" xsl="http://localhost:8080/Xsl-b.xslt"></category>
  </type>
</XslMapper>
```

C# code for parsing;

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string downloadString = client.DownloadString(XslMapperFileAddress);
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(downloadString);
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
            xml.Save(writer);
            string xmlString = builder.ToString();
            xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml, Formatting.Indented, true);
            jsonText = Regex.Replace(jsonText, "(?<=\")(@)(?!.*\":\\s )", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            XslMapper xslMapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XslMapper>(jsonText);
            return xslMapper.XmlMapperTypes;
```

When I serialize this xml into json with json.net I am getting following result;

```
{
  "type": [
    {
      "name": "article",
      "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-a.xslt",
      "category": [
        {
          "name": "1234",
          "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-b.xslt"
        },
        {
          "name": "1234",
          "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-b.xslt"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "slideshow",
      "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-c.xslt",
      "category": {
        "name": "1234",
        "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-b.xslt"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see first category section is parsed as an array (which I am intended to do) and second part converted as object. That's why I am getting error from JSON.NET

How can I parse second part as array like;

```
"category": [
        {
          "name": "1234",
          "xsl": "http://localhost:8080/Services/Xsl-b.xslt"
        }        
      ]
    },
```

Comment: What is the XslMapper class? Is it one you created or is it part of a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) contains example named *Attribute to Force a JSON Array* which says that you have to define a JSON namespace

```
xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'
```

in the XML's root element and add an attribute

```
json:Array='true'
```

to the element you wish to be converted into array (`<category/>` in your case).